# How can I prepend 'wget' to the beginning of each line of 'jq' output?

Tags: shell, pipe, jq

The following command:

```
jq ".[] | .file.url_private_download" *json
```

generates many lines in the form of:

```
"https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T27SFGS2W-F78LH1DN2/download/img_1964.jpg?t=xoxe-243624297126-248125875671-248125975751-cee1f8d9a1"
```

What is the simplest way to prepend a wget command in front of each of these lines ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your command with only a few modifications:

```bash
jq -r '.[] | @sh "wget \(.file.url_private_download)"' *json
```

The changes:

- Use `-r` to get decoded strings as output instead of JSON-encoded strings.
- Create strings that start with `wget`  followed by the value that you need from the structure, using `\(...)` to interpolate the value from the document into the string.
- Use `@sh` to properly quote the generated string for the shell.  This ensures that the interpolated value in each string is safely quoted for use in the shell.

With the above command, the entry that contains the URL that you show is expected to generate the following line as output:

```
wget 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T27SFGS2W-F78LH1DN2/download/img_1964.jpg?t=xoxe-243624297126-248125875671-248125975751-cee1f8d9a1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` to rewrite the start of each line:

```
jq ".[] | .file.url_private_download" *json  | sed 's/^/wget /'
```

which "replaces" the start of the line with whatever the replacement pattern is, here `wget`

Or to `wget` all the files:

```
jq ".[] | .file.url_private_download" *json  | wget -i -
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xargs` to prepend the command you want to each line:

```
jq ".[] | .file.url_private_download" *json | xargs -n1 /bin/echo "wget"
```

Comment: thank you, btw wget has an option to read URLs from a file (but curl on my Mac does not AFAIK)